# Replace start of string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT REPLACE([strUrl], '/myoldurl', '/mynewurl') FROM [UrlRewrite]
```

If `strUrl` is `/myoldurl/myoldurl_something_else`, it returns `/mynewurl/mynewurl_something_else`. I want it to be `/mynewurl/myoldurl_something_else`.

How do I just replace from start of string in SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE([strUrl], '/myoldurl/', '/mynewurl/') FROM [UrlRewrite]
```

to address Martin's point:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [strUrl] = '/myoldurl' THEN '/mynewurl' ELSE REPLACE([strUrl], '/myoldurl/', '/mynewurl/') END FROM [UrlRewrite]
```

or

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN LEFT([strUrl], LEN('/myoldurl')) = '/myoldurl'
        THEN '/mynewurl' + SUBSTRING([strUrl], LEN('/myoldurl')+1, LEN([strUrl]))
    ELSE [strUrl]
    END
FROM [UrlRewrite]
```

Comment: What if the string is just `/myoldurl`?

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can check this simple solution using STUFF function.

```
DECLARE @url varchar(255)='/myoldurl/myoldurl_something_else' 
SELECT STUFF(@url,CHARINDEX('old',@url,1),3,'new')
```

Comment: Warning : This solution will update the first occurrence of oldUrl. To replace only record starting with oldUrl, consider adding a where clause to the update. "where [strUrl] like 'oldUrl%'".  This way, you can run it twice without worries and also handle data you are not aware of.

Comment: Also, replace "3" in the formula with the number of characters you are overwriting on.

Comment: Also it, return null when oldValue is not found, so the "where" clause I suggested is definitely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
SELECT '/mynewurl' + SUBSTRING([strUrl], LEN('/myoldurl')+1,8000) FROM [UrlRewrite]
WHERE [strUrl] LIKE '/myoldurl%'
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace from the start of the string, you could either filter using `LIKE` or if that isn't appropriate to your query, use `CASE`, `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` to conditionally do the replacement

Answer (score 0):

In your example, justo do that:

```
SELECT REPLACE([strUrl], '/myoldurl/', '/mynewurl/') FROM [UrlRewrite]
```